# Simple CSS error (cant think)

Tags: html, css

I have a minor problem with my css in that I have a drop down menu which works fine, however the problem comes when scrolling on items in the drop down the text is not centered in the highlight, it is horizontally but not vertically. I have tried to achieve it by applying a small margin (which isn't a problem), however the margin is applied to the background also thus the background is moved down and the issue remains. See here: http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah. The CSS is located here: http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah/css/drop.css

Comment: Neither of them links seem to work.

Comment: Don't know why you say that, i fixed the second one however the first one definitely works. I just followed it.

Comment: I get a 404 not found error both of the links.

Comment: No they don't, at least not from here:

404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:
  www.letsmine.info/Sundalah (port 80)
Please forward this error screen to www.letsmine.info's WebMaster.

Comment: Odd, loads for me I did change where the domain redirects to, however the files still exist on both servers. Maybe if i refreshed my DNS i would get the error. However Musaul helped me remember the simple piece of code needed to get it to work. Really sometimes i cannot think!

Comment: @Bart @anothershrubery Yer get the error when i flushed my DNS. Server is only for testing anyway so it doesn't matter. If you change the URL to http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah/index.html it works but isn't formatted as the style sheets and images aren't loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `margin` affects the whole box layout, so it will shift the background. Try `padding` instead.

If you want to vertically align the text, and you'll only ever have a single line for each menu entry, set the `line-height` of the (menu entry) box to the same value as the height of the box.

Comment: aul Thanks for pointing out my obvious flaw, Will vote answer soon. I knew about padding but reminding me of the long forgotten line-height was very useful.